Any reason why Authorize.net NetworkTransactionID is not available on production account?
When I try to create a transaction on sandbox the NetworkTransactionID comes back valid alphanumeric string, but when I test production I get NULL back. Account settings appear to be nearly same. Is there any specific reason?
Thank you
